# How to check if array element is null to avoid NullPointerException in Java

Tags: java, arrays, exception, nullpointerexception

I have a partially nfilled array of objects, and when I iterate through them I tried to check to see whether the selected object is `null` before I do other stuff with it. However, even the act of checking if it is `null` seem to through a `NullPointerException`. `array.length` will include all `null` elements as well. How do you go about checking for `null` elements in an array? For example in the following code will throw an NPE for me.

```
Object[][] someArray = new Object[5][];
for (int i=0; i<=someArray.length-1; i++) {
    if (someArray[i]!=null) { //do something
    } 
}
```

Comment: your code doesn't give me a NPR. You might also want to use "i<someArray.length" instead of "i<=someArray.length-1"

Comment: It would throw NPE if you check `!someArray.equals(null)`.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You have more going on than you said.  I ran the following expanded test from your example:

```
public class test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Object[][] someArray = new Object[5][];
        someArray[0] = new Object[10];
        someArray[1] = null;
        someArray[2] = new Object[1];
        someArray[3] = null;
        someArray[4] = new Object[5];

        for (int i=0; i<=someArray.length-1; i++) {
            if (someArray[i] != null) {
                System.out.println("not null");
            } else {
                System.out.println("null");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and got the expected output:

```
$ /cygdrive/c/Program\ Files/Java/jdk1.6.0_03/bin/java -cp . test
not null
null
not null
null
not null
```

Are you possibly trying to check the lengths of someArray[index]?

Answer (score 6):

It does not.

See below. The program you posted runs as supposed.

```
C:\oreyes\samples\java\arrays>type ArrayNullTest.java
public class ArrayNullTest {
    public static void main( String [] args ) {
        Object[][] someArray = new Object[5][];
            for (int i=0; i<=someArray.length-1; i++) {
                 if (someArray[i]!=null ) {
                     System.out.println("It wasn't null");
                 } else {
                     System.out.printf("Element at %d was null \n", i );
                 }
             }
     }
}


C:\oreyes\samples\java\arrays>javac ArrayNullTest.java

C:\oreyes\samples\java\arrays>java ArrayNullTest
Element at 0 was null
Element at 1 was null
Element at 2 was null
Element at 3 was null
Element at 4 was null

C:\oreyes\samples\java\arrays>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
String labels[] = { "MH", null, "AP", "KL", "CH", "MP", "GJ", "OR" }; 

if(Arrays.toString(labels).indexOf("null") > -1)  {
    System.out.println("Array Element Must not be null");
                     (or)
    throw new Exception("Array Element Must not be null");
}        
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------         

For two Dimensional array

String labels2[][] = {{ "MH", null, "AP", "KL", "CH", "MP", "GJ", "OR" },{ "MH", "FG", "AP", "KL", "CH", "MP", "GJ", "OR" };    

if(Arrays.deepToString(labels2).indexOf("null") > -1)  {
    System.out.println("Array Element Must not be null");
                 (or)
    throw new Exception("Array Element Must not be null");
}    
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

same for Object Array    

String ObjectArray[][] = {{ "MH", null, "AP", "KL", "CH", "MP", "GJ", "OR" },{ "MH", "FG", "AP", "KL", "CH", "MP", "GJ", "OR" };    

if(Arrays.deepToString(ObjectArray).indexOf("null") > -1)  {
    System.out.println("Array Element Must not be null");
              (or)
    throw new Exception("Array Element Must not be null");
  }
```

If you want to find a particular null element, you should use for loop as above said .

Answer (score 1):

The given code works for me.  Notice that someArray[i] is always null since you have not initialized the second dimension of the array.

Answer (score 1):

Well, first of all that code doesn't compile.

After removing the extra semicolon after i++, it compiles and runs fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

The example code does not throw an NPE. (there also should not be a ';' behind the i++)

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String s[])
{
    int firstArray[] = {2, 14, 6, 82, 22};
    int secondArray[] = {3, 16, 12, 14, 48, 96};
    int number = getCommonMinimumNumber(firstArray, secondArray);
    System.out.println("The number is " + number);

}
public static int getCommonMinimumNumber(int firstSeries[], int secondSeries[])
{
    Integer result =0;
    if ( firstSeries.length !=0 && secondSeries.length !=0 )
    {
        series(firstSeries);
        series(secondSeries);
        one : for (int i = 0 ; i < firstSeries.length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < secondSeries.length; j++)
                if ( firstSeries[i] ==secondSeries[j])
                {
                    result =firstSeries[i];
                    break one;
                }
                else
                    result = -999;
        }
    }
    else if ( firstSeries == Null || secondSeries == null)
        result =-999;

    else
        result = -999;

    return result;
}

public static int[] series(int number[])
{

    int temp;
    boolean fixed = false;
    while(fixed == false)
    {
        fixed = true;
        for ( int i =0 ; i < number.length-1; i++)
        {
            if ( number[i] > number[i+1])
            {
                temp = number[i+1];
                number[i+1] = number[i];
                number[i] = temp;
                fixed = false;
            }
        }
    }
    /*for ( int i =0 ;i< number.length;i++)
    System.out.print(number[i]+",");*/
    return number;

}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can do it on one line of code (without array declaration):

```
object[] someArray = new object[] 
{
    "aaaa",
    3,
    null
};
bool containsSomeNull = someArray.Any(x => x == null);
```

Comment: This is C# while the question is about Java.